# CSS transitions in different selectors combinations

Tags: css, transition

I have a CSS code, which defines transition to the specified properties like this:

```
button {
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: none;
    transition: background-color .3s ease, box-shadow .3s ease;
}

button:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    background-color: #ddd;
}
```

I have another code applicable to this same element, but with a different selector:

```
button.active {
    color: #808080;
    transition: color .3s ease;
}

button.active:hover {
    color: #ccc;
}
```

As a result, there is an overlap, and only one transition works.
Is it possible to combine these  CSS transitions to make them work together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just combine them.

```
button.active {
  color: #808080;
  transition: background-color .3s ease, box-shadow .3s ease, color .3s ease;
}
button.active:hover {
  color: #ccc;
}
```

Or use `all`(totally depends on what you are trying to achieve).

```
button.active {
  color: #808080;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}
button.active:hover {
  color: #ccc;
}
```

Comment: Almost exactly what I'd suggest, but it seems like it would make more sense to apply the `transition: all` to the plain `button` selector rather than `button.active`.

Comment: I think `transition: all` is the best solution for me now, but i meant something like this: `transition: inherit, color .3s ease...`. Has CSS something similar?